# Facebook App Action Not Appearing on Friend's View of my Timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I followed the tutorial on Facebook: [Facebook App Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/)
up to the point where you post actions (Cook) a recipe.

I also followed an outdated tutorial which is similar to the new Facebook tutorial found here: [Facebook App Tutorial 2](http://onlytipsandtricks.com/facebook/how-to-publish-actions-on-timeline/).

The actions do appear on my own news ticker and my own timeline when I view my profile. However, when I login with a test account to view my own profile, the app's actions are not shown on the test account's view of my timeline or the test account's news ticker.

I am friends with my test account. I also made sure privacy settings are public for the actions of the app.
I was wondering what steps I am missing before the actions of the app appear when others view my Timeline and their news ticker.
Do I have to submit the action in the Open Graph tab?

Sandbox mode is disabled. The test account is able to go to the app page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the test user you created listed as a `Tester` or `Developer` of the application? If you action has not been approved by Facebook, only users listed in the `Roles` tab of your App Settings will be able to publish and see the action on the timeline.

Comment: Thank you that answers my question, I just added the test account which is not a test user but an alternate facebook account as a tester and am able to see the actions. I wish they explained this more clearly in the tutorial.